# then and else parse error in Haskell List Comprehension

Tags: haskell, if-statement, list-comprehension

So there was an example in [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) that I wanted to recast using list comprehension. Basically it should be a simple function `f:[a]->[Char]` as follows

```
let sayMe xs = [ if x <- [1..5] then show x else "Not a desired value" | x <- xs]
```

Unfortunately when I try to define the function I get the following error:

`parse error in if statement: missing required then and else clauses`

However, I **do** have the `then` and `else` clauses there and my function isn't, as far as I can tell, very far off from another example in the book which I have verified as working:

```
let sayMe xs = [if x<10 then "Bang!" else "Boom!"|x<-xs, odd x]
```

I know that there are other ways to do this, but I'd like to understand why this particular method isn't working the way I think it should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `if-then-else` expression has three parts: a condition, a `True` branch, and a `False` branch. Each of these parts must be an *expression*. `x <- [1..5]` is not an expression; it's part of list comprehension syntax. You could express that concept with an expression, however.

```
[ if 1 <= x && x <= 5 then show x else "Not a desired value" | x <- xs ]
```

If the things you're interested in are not consecutive, you can use the `elem` function:

```
[ if x `elem` [1,17,94,12] then show x else "Not a desired value" | x <- xs ]
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Odd that the expression x<-set isn't considered an "expression".  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Tshimanga, it's not actually odd. Drawing from a list is quite different from checking if a value is in a list. If the syntax worked for both, it would sometimes be ambiguous. This is not the Haskell way. Also, you'll soon learn other ways `<-` is used that have nothing to do with lists.